# How to pass json data as query parameter in GET call using Restassured

Tags: java, rest-assured

I am able to pass the JSON data as Query Parameters in which I am passing particular **kit_config_id** in the form of **HasMap**. Now I want the API to return the data related to only specified **kit_config_id** but its giving me all records.

What wrong I am doing here?

```
// Request object using RestAssured
RequestSpecification httpRequest = RestAssured.given();

HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
params.put("kit_config_id", "60db53ec7a334172b005b692");

Response response = httpRequest.given().baseUri("https://qa-api-test.com").param("query", params).when().get("/imageProps");
```

Complete Url of GET call is : `https://qa-api-tests.com/imageProps?params={"query": {"kit_config_id": "60db53ec7a334172b005b692"}}`

Comment: What makes you sure you’re ‘passing JSON data as query parameters’? Have you tried calling it from postman (or similar) to check how you’re supposed to serialising the JSON? Are you sure you need it to be JSON, not just use the `queryParam` method on `RequestSpecification`?

Comment: I have tried below way also but again its giving me all records : 


HashMap<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
params.put("kit_config_id", "60db0d5d7a334172b005b665");

HashMap<String, Object> query = new HashMap<String, Object>();
query.put("query", params);

// Add Base URI by using RestAssured
String url = RestAssured.baseURI = "https://qa-api-test.com";

// Request object using RestAssured
RequestSpecification httpRequest = RestAssured.given().queryParams(     query);

Response response = httpRequest.request(Method.GET);

Comment: I’m not sure that answers any of my questions. What are you expecting your query string to look like?

Answer (score 1):

If you want query like this

```
/imageProps?params={"query":{"kit_config_id":"60db0d5d7a334172b005b665"}}
```

Using this:

```
HashMap<String, Object> kit_config = new HashMap<>();
kit_config.put("kit_config_id", "60db0d5d7a334172b005b665");
HashMap<String, Object> query = new HashMap<>();
query.put("query", kit_config);

RestAssured.given().log().all().baseUri("your-url")
        .queryParams("params", query)
        .when().get("/imageProps");
```

If you want query like this

```
/imageProps?kit_config_id=60db53ec7a334172b005b692
```

Just need:

```
HashMap<String, Object> kit_config = new HashMap<>();
kit_config.put("kit_config_id", "60db0d5d7a334172b005b665");

RestAssured.given().log().all().baseUri("https://postman-echo.com")
        .queryParams(kit_config)
        .when().get("/imageProps");
```

Comment: thanks a lot, it worked like a charm for me...actually I was doing a silly mistake earlier ...was not adding "params"